# How to change mid mouse button function for a keyboard key?

Tags: shortcut

**"The Summary"**
I need to change shortcuts that involves, mid mouse button and movement of the mouse, specifically "The shortcut for the Pan View Function" and the user preferences only allows me to put a single key or the mouse only. How can I set a combination of keys and mouse for a shortcut?

**"The large explanation"**
For medical reasons I stop using mouse, now i use just the pen of my tablet, the thing is that the button on the pen that I mapped to be the central button of the mouse is breaking easily with the continuous use, I bought a second pen and now it is begin to fail, I want to replace the mid mouse button function with any other key "I know i have to do it shortcut by short cut, that is not the problem" the problem is that the user preferences menu only allows me to change it for a single key, I need a combination of the movement of the mouse and a key, How can i do it?

[image]

Thanks Duarte Farrajota Ramos and thanks a lot cegaton that was exactly what I was looking for, thanks man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use blender with a wacom pen and no mouse.

In the System preferences > Input section I enabled **Emulate 3 Button Mouse**.

On the interface I **drag the pen while holding**:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> to zoom in or out.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> to rotate.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> to move up down or sideways.

Answer (score 1):

Click the little arrow to the left to expand the key mapping properties.

There you can choose from the predefined modifier key combinations (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>), or use any other as modifier.

[image]